# How to implement adwords conversion code with Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, google-ads-api

Where to add adwords conversion code on prestashop shopping website, currently I don't want conversion value. Just guide me on which file I required to put my code and how.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert your AdWords conversion code at the end of the `order-confirmation.tpl` file of your theme.

Answer (score 1):

As Yenshirak says, you had to put it on themes/YOUR_THEME/order-confirmation.tpl

You have top put the script variables between tags {literal} and {/literal} like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
{literal}
   var google_conversion_id = X;
   var google_conversion_language = "X";
   var google_conversion_format = "2";  
   var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";  
   var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";  
   var google_conversion_value = 0;
{/literal}
   /* ]]> */
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
   /script>
   <noscript>
   <div style="display:inline;">
   <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/
  ?label=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&guid=ON&script=0"/>
   </div>
   </noscript>
```